# C# - Unable to declare a private variable in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm unable to declare a private variable in the class constructor in C#. I faced this issue when I was trying to declare a private DateTime variable. Here's the code I had when I ran into this problem:

```
namespace FirstCSApp
{
    public class MyStopWatch
    {
        public MyStopWatch()
        {
            private DateTime _start = new DateTime();
        }
    }
}
```

There are two errors that VS gives me:
1) After the opening curly bracket, I get an error saying "*expected }*" and, 
2) At the last curly bracket, I get an error that says "*Type or namespace definition , or end-of-file expected*"
The way I resolved the issue was to declare the variable outside the constructor and then initialize it in the constructor. However, I still don't understand why I'm unable to declare and initialize a private variable inside the constructor while declaring the variable without a public/private modifier works just fine.

Comment: Please read some c# tutorials... (BTW when not explicitly writing an access modifier the default is private). Declare outside of constructor, initialize in

Comment: Not sure which language you come from, but in c#, a variable declared inside a method is only visible to that method. You should read some c# documentation. The MSDN is a great place for this

Comment: It is important to get the terminology straight: things declared inside methods are called "local variables", while things declared outside methods are called "fields".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I still don't understand why I'm unable to declare and initialize a private variable inside the constructor while declaring the variable without a public/private modifier works just fine.

This is just the way the C# spec is written. Class-level instance variables (public or private) cannot be declared inside class methods or constructors.

Check out the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) for discussion around C# classes.

Comment: Noob  mistake :p I still hadn't made a distinction between class-instance variable and a local one! :p

Answer (score 2):

> I still don't understand why I'm unable to declare and initialize a private variable inside the constructor while declaring the variable without a public/private modifier works just fine.

Because declaring a "variable" with public/private modifier outside methods and constructors creates a *field*, a different thing from a *local variable*, which is what you get when you declare a variable inside a method or a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on variable scope.  If you intend to "share" usage of this variable with other methods of your class, the variable must be declared at the class scope.

Any variable declared within a class METHOD will only be accessible from within that method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx